# Why in the definition of GHZ state only the $M>2$ case is considered?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

I have a basic question about the definition of the [Greenberger–Horne–Zeilinger state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state) , which is defined as the maximally entangled state. Why is it only considered applicable for subsystems $M > 2$, why would the definition not apply or why is it not preferable to consider states where $M = 2$?

Comment: I've removed the second half of your post as it has no bearing on the initial question or with the title. You're perfectly welcome to [ask it separately](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A GHZ in $M=2$ would be $|00\rangle+|11\rangle$. Sure you could still call it a GHZ, but it is not very useful because this state already has a name: it's a Bell state.

A standard reference to understand entanglement and how it is measured is [Gühne and Toth 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2803).